# What's the best set of runes for a fast jungle with Warwick?

Tags: league-of-legends

Hey guys I'm looking for some information about Runes and Routes for jungle as Warwick.

Currently I am using this set of Runes:

- Attack Speed Marks and Glyphs.
- Armor Seals.
- Armor Penetration Quint.

I'm not very sure if this set provides the fastest jungle clear.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about?  We need something with concrete answers, and asking for "best" anything is generally subjective.  Do you want to know what runes help Warwick clear the jungle as fast as possible?

Comment: If we define "best" by highest win rate, champion.gg usually has the statistically highest win rate builds for all champions in the game, and for the most recent patch. A couple caveats: the builds are likely for best case scenarios and do not encompass the whole of scenarios you may face as jungle Warwick, but it gives a pretty good idea of what you should be aiming for in your build. In practice, I use it as an opportunity to ask questions like,"What conditions do these items work best in" and "What do these items do that other items cannot provide?"

Answer (score 3):

I have no hard numbers but I will explain the reasoning for the choices.

My recommendation: **Flat attack speed runes in every slot**.

The reasoning. His passive scales perfectly with AS and most Warwick builds are based around on hit effects. (Wits end, his passive, Bloodrazor). AS helps him clear camps faster, gives him more sustain and scales extremely well late game.

---

**Armour pen runes** - These are a no go in my opinion. 10 Armour pen is enough for jungle creeps to have 0 armour, however Warwick doesn't scale very well with these runes. They may be good for optimal jungle clearing time, however I wouldn't recommend them due to their usefulness falling off pretty hard late game.

**Attack damage runes** - Warwick doesn't scale so well with AD, so as above, I would not recommend them.

**Flat armour seals** - I would recommend these on every jungler, except for Warwick. He has build in sustain. You will want to build a wiggles anyway, so the cloth armour will be more than enough for you.

**Magic pen runes** - These are very strong for lanewick and scale well late game. However, they are not optimal for faster jungle clearing times.

**Magic resistance glyphs** - These are an option instead of attack speed glyphs. This decision makes your clear time slower. Warwick tend to end up with a fair amount of magic resist through most builds anyway, so I'd say AS runes are preferable unless you are against an extremely AP heavy team.

**Movement speed Quints** - These are another option for WW. He will be able to travel between camps faster as well as help his ganks. His bloodscent makes these a bit redundant later on in the game as you will probably be moving faster than everyone else already anyway. Attack speed quints are probably still preferable due to sustain they give.

Comment: I really disagree with this answer.  Though all attack speed may give the fastest jungle clear, it will make him very weak mid-late game.  If you max `Hunter's Call` and build attack speed items, you're going to hit the attack speed limit.

Comment: @Toast you will not be hitting 2.5 attacks per second with most builds. What AS items would you be buying to achieve this out of curiosity?

Comment: Wit's End and Bloodrazor both spring to mind.

Comment: With those items, and AS runes, WW will still not be at max attack speed. If you disagree feel free to post an answer. I am interested to see what you recommend. There are only two champions I run with a full AS rune page in the jungle, that is WW and Yi.

Comment: I Used to use this build and as @Toast said, the mid-late game is very damage about this. 1- You don't **need** the AS cap to be a good WW. 2- Your answer is NOT wrong, but I believe it could be a little more improved. I need test WW again (I don't play him have a BIG while (8months I believe)) to make a good answer.

Comment: I relent @theorise.  Full attack speed probably does provide the _fastest_ jungle clear, though I still prefer armor yellows and scaling MR blues for a stronger late game.

Comment: I tested this Full Atk Speed and it works great early game but in the end not so much. Going to try adding some Armor runes now and see how that works out.

Comment: All of Warwicks damage is based off of lowering the cooldown on his Q and on hit effects. (Wits end, blood razor). He naturally builds tanky and should NOT need armour runes because - his sustain is so good at level 1 it is unnecessary and because core items on him include randiun's/frozen heart + madreds. These give more than enough armour. MPen runes are the only other option I would consider on him as MPen scales nicely with on hit effects (passive, ult) + his Q.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run a full page of attack speed on my ww jungle, with the jungle remake i didnt care for it much so i switched out attack speed quints for gp10 quints i found it helped if i got counter jungled, and i was also not losing out on so much money if i waited too long for a gank. my build is more of a utility ww i get pretty tanky and if i get to late game im pretty unkillable unless focused hard. my build is usually wriggles, mercs, spirit vistage, wits end, and then end with GA if the game is dragged out.

Answer (score 0):

well i recomend armor penetration and attack speed with magic penetration in s6 purely because WW is the master of sustain. but even more so because if you have wits end and bloodrazor your going to scale off the damage your w, and q, give you. so you can gank, jungle WW not have to worry about hp or your targets getting away. for the problem of armor however mid game(lvl 8-10 or so) your gonna wanna see enemy team and how they are building, then choose titanic hydra, deadmans plate, spirit visage depend on if they are a AD or AP team and if they are scaling AP or AD.

Comment: I tried to add some grammar into your post but since I don't play LoL I couldn't understand half of what you were saying. Could you try and make some readable sentences and break your text up a bit?